# R animation-package: Animation of curve only shows one blank frame and ends

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2

I have a problem with the animation of a curve.
I have a data.table that stores the points I want to plot for each curve. In each successive frame I want to plot the next column from that data.table.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(animation)
    x <- seq(1, 10, 0.1)
    y1 <- x
    y2 <- 2*x
    y3 <- 3*x
    y4 <- 4*x
    y5 <- 5*x

    test <- data.table(x = x,
    y1 = y1,
    y2 = y2,
    y3 = y3,
    y4 = y4,
    y5 = y5)
```

The function that draws the ith curve is

```
drawCurve <- function(i){
    cols <- c(quote(y1), quote(y2), quote(y3), quote(y4), quote(y5))
    plot(test[, x], test[, eval(cols[[i]])])
}
```

The function that draws frame after frame is

```
drawAnimation <- function(){
  for(i in 1:5){
    dev.hold()
    drawCurve(i)
    ani.pause()
  }
}
```

Now the following call to produce the video is

```
 oopt <- ani.options(interval = 1, nmax = 5)

oopts = ani.options(ffmpeg = "D:/ffmpeg-20141030-git-7f24e1e-win32-static/bin/ffmpeg.exe")
if (.Platform$OS.type != "windows") ani.options(ffmpeg = "ffmpeg")
saveVideo({
    drawAnimation()
}, video.name = "Curve.mp4", other.opts = "-b 800k")
ani.options(oopts)
```

where each frame should be displayed for 1 second.
But it results in a video, 1 second long, showing a black screen.
The functions drawCurve() and drawAnimation() work as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think this is a data.table issue. What happens when you do: `plot(test[["x"]], test[[cols[i]]])` where `cols` is just a character vector instead? Also, if you do the same on a `data.frame`, what happens?

Comment: Thanks @Arun. I tried your suggestion, but the result is the same. Accessing the column like this works inside of the script. So I think you are right, this isn't a data.table issue. I removed the keyword. I didn't know that you can call a column like this. This is better in readability, too.

Comment: I noticed that `ffmpeg`s output text says **frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      33kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=  91.2kbits/s**. Maybe fps=0.0 points to the issue?

Comment: FullCircle, I don't know the answer (haven't used `animation` package), but my intent was to *rule out* data.table as the potential problem, so that you (or others) can focus on the other packages. Good luck!